# How to use Chisel C++ emulator

Tags: chisel

How to use the C++ files generated by the Chisel compiler? the documentations are not clear on this, is there any other source to point me to it? I am really clueless on this, specially that I don't know C++.

Say for example for a simple adder circuit `Adder.scala` I will get the following files related to the emulator: 
`Adder.cpp`, `Adder.h`, `Adder-emulator.cpp`, `emul_api.h`, `emulator.h` and `sim_api.h`.
For which I can compile by running

```
g++ Adder.cpp Adder-emulator.cpp
```

This generates the output `a.out` running this in the terminal generates three more files that I have no clue what they are.
`00003710.cmd`, `00003710.in` and `00003710.out`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ code is used to build an emulation of your design. You need to also define a tester that will drive the emulation, using `poke()` to set signal values, and `peek()` or `expect()` to read them.

You should not be compiling the C++ yourself. If you pass the `--genHarness` and `--test` options to Chisel, it will compile the C++ code, build the emulation and run your tester to drive it.

Have a look at the [chisel-tutorial](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel-tutorial) code for examples of this process.

Comment: OK I was confused the testbench written in the scala code is itself the C++ emulator? is that it?

Comment: I have done that I get the PASSED and Success message in the terminal, is that all? sorry for asking too much but I am relatively new to chisel.

Comment: The test bench (written in Scala) communicates (currently via shared memory) with the emulation built from C++ code. If you're referring to the tutorial code, yes, PASSED and Success are an indication that a simulation of the design was built and passed the tests written for it.